# Dynamic UI Controls in Android

Tags: android

I am in a situation like i have to generate UI Controls like Button,Switcher,Progress Bar, Label text etc based on my list Items .

I am looking for a way to generate the controls in a View and add Views with generated controls in a Layout .

Can anyone give me a proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Fragments?
Google docs about this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

and little tutorial [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org) source code. The Android version of Metawidget makes extensive use of generating Views and Layouts at runtime (e.g. see org.metawidget.android.widget.widgetbuilder.AndroidWidgetBuilder). You may even find Metawidget itself will suit your needs (it's designed to be embedded into projects for use-cases such as this).